# First and last not null fields over partitions

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

I have a table like this:

| EventID | EventTime | AttrA | AttrB |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-10-01 00:00:01.000000 | null | null |
| 1 | 2022-10-01 00:00:02.000000 | a | null |
| 1 | 2022-10-01 00:00:03.000000 | b | 1 |
| 1 | 2022-10-01 00:00:04.000000 | null | null |
| 2 | 2022-10-01 00:01:01.000000 | aa | 11 |
| 2 | 2022-10-01 00:01:02.000000 | bb | null |
| 2 | 2022-10-01 00:01:03.000000 | null | null |
| 2 | 2022-10-01 00:01:04.000000 | aa | 22 |

and I want to jump across the records to return the first and last **not null** AttrA and AttrB values for each eventID based on the eventTime. Each eventID can have multiple records so we can't know where the not nulls may be. So the wished results would be:

| EventID | FirstAttrA | LastAttrA | FirstAttrB | LastAttrB |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | b | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | aa | aa | 11 | 22 |

What I did is to add `row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY event_id) ORDER BY event_time ASC)` and then again `DESC` and then have multiple `CTEs` like this:

```
WITH enhanced_table AS
(
   SELECT
      eventID,
      attrA,
      attrB,
      row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY event_id) ORDER BY event_time ASC) as rn,
      row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY event_id) ORDER BY event_time DESC) as reversed_rn
),
first_events_with_attrA AS 
(
   SELECT 
      eventID,
      FIRST(attrA) OVER (PARTITION BY eventID ORDER BY rn ASC) AS url
   FROM enhanced_table
   WHERE attrA IS NOT NULL
)...
```

But I need one CTE which scans again the table for each case I want (for this example 4 CTEs in total). It works, but it is slow.

Is there a way to grab the values I am interested in in a more efficient way?

Comment: I added the reversed_rn for another challenge that my Query has to deal with, which is not mentioned. I included it only because it is going to be there anyway so the solution may(?) take advantage of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Need to build Row Numbers , you can directly use native `SparkSQL` Functions [FIRST](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#first) & [LAST](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#last) with `isIgnoreNull`  as True to achieve the intended results -

#### Data Preparation

```
s = StringIO("""
EventID,EventTime,AttrA,AttrB
1,2022-10-01 00:00:01.000000,,
1,2022-10-01 00:00:02.000000,a,
1,2022-10-01 00:00:03.000000,b,1
1,2022-10-01 00:00:04.000000,,
2,2022-10-01 00:01:01.000000,aa,11
2,2022-10-01 00:01:02.000000,bb,
2,2022-10-01 00:01:03.000000,,
2,2022-10-01 00:01:04.000000,aa,22
"""
)

inp_schema = StructType([
                      StructField('EventID',IntegerType(),True)
                     ,StructField('EventTime',StringType(),True)
                     ,StructField('AttrA',StringType(),True)
                     ,StructField('AttrB',DoubleType(),True)
                    ]
                   )


df = pd.read_csv(s,delimiter=',')


sparkDF = sql.createDataFrame(df,schema=inp_schema)\
             .withColumn('AttrA',F.when(F.isnan(F.col('AttrA')),None).otherwise(F.col('AttrA')))\
             .withColumn('AttrB',F.when(F.isnan(F.col('AttrB')),None).otherwise(F.col('AttrB')))


sparkDF.show(truncate=False)

+-------+--------------------------+-----+-----+
|EventID|EventTime                 |AttrA|AttrB|
+-------+--------------------------+-----+-----+
|1      |2022-10-01 00:00:01.000000|null |null |
|1      |2022-10-01 00:00:02.000000|a    |null |
|1      |2022-10-01 00:00:03.000000|b    |1.0  |
|1      |2022-10-01 00:00:04.000000|null |null |
|2      |2022-10-01 00:01:01.000000|aa   |11.0 |
|2      |2022-10-01 00:01:02.000000|bb   |null |
|2      |2022-10-01 00:01:03.000000|null |null |
|2      |2022-10-01 00:01:04.000000|aa   |22.0 |
+-------+--------------------------+-----+-----+
```

#### First & Last

```
sparkDF.registerTempTable("INPUT")

sql.sql("""
SELECT
    EventID,
    FIRST(AttrA,True) as First_AttrA,
    LAST(AttrA,True) as Last_AttrA,
    FIRST(AttrB,True) as First_AttrB,
    LAST(AttrB,True) as Last_AttrB
FROM INPUT
GROUP BY 1
""").show()

+-------+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+
|EventID|First_AttrA|Last_AttrA|First_AttrB|Last_AttrB|
+-------+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+
|      1|          a|         b|        1.0|       1.0|
|      2|         aa|        aa|       11.0|      22.0|
+-------+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+
```

Comment: it's incredible how easy it was at the end. many thanks